# ActiveRecord not returning row, but returns after second duplicate row?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an empty table called users. I create a new user via:

```
User.create :fb_id => fb_id
```

It successfully creates an entry.

Then I query it via:

```
User.first(:include => :cookies, :conditions => {:cookies => {:opened => false} , :fb_id => fb_id})
```

returns `nil`!!

I check the table and the user is there.
So I create a new, duplicate user via:

```
User.create :fb_id => fb_id
```

Now there's exact two row with same fb_id. If I query now just like before:

```
User.first(:include => :cookies, :conditions => {:cookies => {:opened => false} , :fb_id => fb_id})
```

it returns the new user now with id 2!

What's going on? I've been trying to debug it for 3-4 hours but can't figure it out.
Thanks

My Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :cookies
    has_many :fortunes, :through => :cookies
end

class Cookie < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :fortune
end

class Fortune < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :cookies
    has_many :users, :through => :cookies
end
```

Comment: What does the `:cookies` association look like?

Comment: Updated with Users table

Comment: Does your cookies table have a default value for `opened`?  If not, perhaps you should check for not true instead of false.

Comment: @SeanHill That still doesn't explain why I need two users with same fb_id for the query to return a row. My cookies table is empty, so is fortune.

Comment: How are the cookies and fortunes created?

Comment: @OxSina Then you need to perform 'or' operation.

Comment: @SeanHill They are never created. My DB is empty at the moment other than those two rows. My goal is to search for a user with a specific fb_id, and include (in that one query) all that user's cookies who's opened = false

Comment: Do you want to return the user even if he has no unopened cookies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that Rails will use a `left outer join` when using `include`.  However, when joining, the associated row, all values will be `null`.  Therefore, you should use something like:

```
User.first(:include => :cookies, 
           :conditions => ["cookies.opened <> ? AND fb_id = ?", true, fb_id])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  User.first(:include => :cookies, :conditions => ["cookies.opened=? or users.fb_id=?",false, fb_id])
```